# Java lambdas thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, thread-safety

As I read previously, lambdas can be cached. In a multi-threaded environment, if we run the following code, can it be the case that Thread1 starts the execution of foo method with a parameter of "appple" then stops, lets say at the line where we concatenate the string with a smile, then Thread2 comes in with an "orange" parameter and executes everything, then Thread1 wake up and continue, but instead of concatenate the "apple" its concatenate an "orange" with the smile?

```
static void foo(String s){
  Consumer<String> consumer = string -> {
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    string = string + ":)";
    System.out.println(string);
  };
  consumer.accept(s);
}
```

Context (but it really doesn't matter much):
I want to store Strategies in an AbstractFactory using lambdas, instead of class instances like in the old school GoF book. (This way I can provide an API for client code where they can inline some short lambdas if they want, instead getting my longer lambdas from the factory.) But if I return a strategy using "return new Strategy1()" then that instance can be thread safe, because every thread can get an own instance. But if a return like this: "return s -> s.toUpperCase()" this lambda can be cached.

Comment: Only things that can be shared are cached. If a lambda captures anything, then a new instance will be allocated for every thread. Otherwise there is no harm in even sharing the actual instance.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. In practice this will end up as a method and any 'caching' you speak of is both [A] caching the entire class, not just this one lambda, and [B] just a cache of the code, not any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The invocation of a lambda works the same as a method invocation, that is local variables in the body and the parameters are specific to the invocation. Multiple invocations do not share local variables and parameters. So - just like with methods - unless the lambda is stateful (that is, modifies or stores in fields or objects outside of the lambda), multiple invocations of the same lambda will not interfere and will be threadsafe.